# Tooltip appears for all nivo charts except nivo/line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using nivo charts and the tooltip is not appearing only for my line chart. I copy pasted the example here:

https://nivo.rocks/line/

The chart appears fine with a crosshair but no tooltip appears. When I copy paste other chart examples they work perfectly with a tooltip appearing. I am not sure how to go about solving this as it only happens for the line chart.

Answer (score 1):

I installed a previous version and then reinstalled the current version and it works now. I am not sure what the cause was.